Java Dynamic Resource Discovery
The following code creates a list of classes and interfaces in the specified package.
public static List<Class> getClasses(ClassLoader loader, String pack) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) loader.getResource(pack.replace('.', '/')).getContent()));
    List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
        if (line.endsWith(".class")) {
            classes.add(Class.forName(pack + "." + line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf('.'))));
        }
    }
    reader.close();
    return classes;
}

This code works, however please advise when it may NOT work, such as when the code is obfuscated or when a Java binary is converted to a native binary using GraalVM or what else?

You have several issues with your question: 1. Lack of Research 2. Unclear or Broad 3. Code Dumps. It would be much better if you could update your question accordingly.

I mean, when the call to loader.getResource(pkg) or reader.readLine() from that resource, or Class.forName(clazz) may fall -- after the code is obfuscated or Java binary is converted to a native binary using GraalVM ?
Or this code is problem-free?

This can fail at any time due to the assumption that loader.getResource(pack.replace('.', '/')).getContent() with a package name will return an InputStream. This is not guaranteed anywhere. Further, even if this expression evaluates to an InputStream, there is no guaranty about its contents.
